# RestFull Api with JAX-RS and JPA returns empty json

Tags: jpa, glassfish, jax-rs

I have written following code to get json from glassfish server:

```
@Stateless
@Path("user")
public class UserProvider {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @GET    
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public User getUserById(@PathParam("id") long id) {
        User user = em.find(User.class, id);
        System.out.println(user);
        return user;
    }
}
```

I am expecting the json formatted user information when i hit the url localhost:8080//project/rest/user/1.
But i am receiving empty json object as {} even though the print statement prints the user object.

I am not able to understand what is the thing i am doing wrong.

Entity Class:
Added Getters.

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    private String password;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might need a @XmlRootElement annotation in your User class.

Comment: Is that all you have in User? Because it lacks the getters that the JSON serializer will use. XmlRootElement is useless for JSON.

Comment: I tried adding getters for the User class but still it don't work

Comment: Which version of Glassfish are you using? I'd like to test it

Comment: The posted code is not valid. `self` is not Java. Show us your REAL code. Not some product of your imagination, unless you want us to give you imaginary solutions instead of real ones.

Comment: It worked fine for me. I used your same code, taking out the persistence stuff, since you said that's not the problem. Added setters to the User.class. In the resource method, I just created a `new User` and set the fields. I create an `Application` class with the `@ApplciationPath("/rest")` annotation and overrode the `getClasses` method with a `Set` containing the `User.class`. `http://localhost:8080/jaxrs-glassfish/rest/user/1` returns the json

Comment: Hey @peeskillet Thanks for the solution. I just added setters to the User Class and it started working. But not sure why the setters are so imp.

Comment: the fields who's getters and setters are available. Only those fields are coming in the json output.

Comment: Most likely, because there are no annotation to hint the serializer/deseriaizer, it uses JavaBean properties. JavaBeans properties are a set of matching getter/setter methods use to set/get the field value, and must conform to the JavaBean naming convention. Most data binding serializers/deserializers work like this. Not too familiar with Jersey (the Glassfish jaxrs impl) and what serializer it uses under the hood, but I would this is the problem with it